# wine32:i386 : Depends: libwine:i386 (= 3.0-1ubuntu1) whenever I try to install -anything- and when I try to uninstall wine

Tags: wine, dependencies, repository

Months ago I tried to install wine and since then, whenever I try to install something, anything, I get this error. I tried to uninstall wine but, unfortunately whenever I try to uninstall it I also get this error. I have too many back up to take and set up, so I can't just do a clean Ubuntu install right now but as you might guess, this has been very difficult for me! practically making it impossible to use my machine.

This is the error I get:

```
   wine32:i386 : Depends: libwine:i386 (= 3.0-1ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
     wine64 : Depends: libwine (= 3.0-1ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
```

I did read some comments on repositories, and these are the ones I can see in the list that mentions wine:

```
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-wine-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list:# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu bionic main # disabled on upgrade to bionic
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-wine-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-wine-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list.distUpgrade:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-wine-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list.distUpgrade:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-wine-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list.save:# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu bionic main # disabled on upgrade to bionic
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-wine-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list:# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu bionic main # disabled on upgrade to bionic
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-wine-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-wine-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list.distUpgrade:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-wine-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list.distUpgrade:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-wine-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list.save:# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu bionic main # disabled on upgrade to bionic
```

Some has advised to remove these but I am not sure if I need to go for all? I have many other packages as well, do I remove xenial?? not remove xenial??. Also, I am not sure how to delete them as I can't install synaptic package manager and the like due to the error mentioned above just as any other package.

How can I fix this? I do not wish to keep wine at all, I just want to fix this issue
-------------------------EDIT---------------------------------------------

```
 grep -r ^deb /etc/apt/ --include="*.list"


/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://archive.canonical.com/ bionic partner
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/obsproject-ubuntu-obs-studio-bionic.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/obsproject/obs-studio/ubuntu bionic main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
```

---

```
apt-cache policy wine32:i386 libwine:i386 wine64 libwine
wine32:i386:
  Installed: 3.0-1ubuntu1
  Candidate: 3.0-1ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 3.0-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libwine:i386:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.0-1ubuntu1
  Version table:
     3.0-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe i386 Packages
wine64:
  Installed: 3.0-1ubuntu1
  Candidate: 3.0-1ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 3.0-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libwine:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.0-1ubuntu1
  Version table:
     3.0-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
```

---

```
dpkg -l | grep -i wine
ii  q4wine                                        1.3.6-2                                         amd64        Qt GUI for wine (WINE)
iU  wine-stable                                   3.0-1ubuntu1                                    all          Windows API implementation - standard suite
rc  wine1.6                                       1:1.6.2-0ubuntu14.2                             amd64        Microsoft Windows Compatibility Layer (Binary Emulator and Library)
ii  wine1.8                                       1:1.8.0-0ubuntu1~ubuntu15.10.1~ppa1             amd64        Microsoft Windows Compatibility Layer (Binary Emulator and Library)
ii  wine1.8-amd64                                 1:1.8.0-0ubuntu1~ubuntu15.10.1~ppa1             amd64        Microsoft Windows Compatibility Layer (64-bit support)
ii  wine1.8-i386:i386                             1:1.8.0-0ubuntu1~ubuntu15.10.1~ppa1             i386         Microsoft Windows Compatibility Layer (32-bit support)
iU  wine32:i386                                   3.0-1ubuntu1                                    i386         Windows API implementation - 32-bit binary loader
iU  wine64                                        3.0-1ubuntu1                                    amd64        Windows API implementation - 64-bit binary loader
ii  winetricks                                    0.0+20180217-1                                  all          package manager for Wine to install software easily
```

Comment: OK, let's start from the beginning - add the output of the following commands - `grep -r ^deb /etc/apt/ --include="*.list` , `apt-cache policy wine32:i386 libwine:i386 wine64 libwine` , `dpkg -l | grep -i wine` to the question.

Comment: Hi, thanks, I edited to add the outputs to the comments.

Comment: Do you really need Wine? Do you plan to use it?

Comment: No, not at all, I just want the errors gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend to remove Wine repository with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r "deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main"
```

and remove related packages with low-level commands

```
sudo dpkg -P --force-all wine1.6
sudo dpkg -P --force-all wine1.8 
sudo dpkg -P --force-all wine1.8-amd64
sudo dpkg -P --force-all wine1.8-i386:i386
```

and normal high-level commands:

```
sudo apt-get purge q4wine wine-stable wine32:i386 wine64 winetricks
```